# Oracle database batch update pl_sql

Tags: oracle

Im trying to 'translate' a month table, with pl_sql 6.0 program.

I would like to run all these instructions below at once, in a very simple code, like 'select the instructions and hit F8', all at once.

Problem is:

without ";" between each instruction, i get: ORA-00933 command not properly ended
with ";" between each instruction, im getting: ORA-00911 invalid character
im new on oracle database, so...what i am not seeing? Thanks in advance.

```
update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='JANEIRO' where t.m_description like '%JANUARY%'
update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='FEVEREIRO' where t.m_description like '%FEBRUARY%'
update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='MARÇO' where  t.m_description like '%MARCH%'
update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='ABRIL' where t.m_description like '%APRIL%'
... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Update using `CASE` statement.

```
update TIME_TABLE t 
set t.m_description = (
    case when t.m_description like '%JANUARY%' then 'JANEIRO' 
        when t.m_description like '%FEBRUARY%' then 'FEVEREIRO'
        when t.m_description like '%MARCH%' then 'MARÇO'
        when t.m_description like '%APRIL%' then 'ABRIL'
    else t.m_description
    end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put these instruction within BEGIN ... END, like this:

```
BEGIN
   update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='JANEIRO' where t.m_description like '%JANUARY%'
   update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='FEVEREIRO' where t.m_description like '%FEBRUARY%'
   update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='MARÇO' where  t.m_description like '%MARCH%'
   update TIME_TABLE t set t.m_description='ABRIL' where t.m_description like '%APRIL%'
   ... and so on
END;
/
```